# Asymptotic size of a given dominating set in a random geometric graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, geometric-probability

We consider a [random geometric (undirected) graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_geometric_graph) $G=(V,E)$ ($n=|V|$):

- to each vertex $u \in V=\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ a random point $P(u) \in [a;b]^2$ is associated.
- two vertices $u$ and $v$ are connected iff $|P(u)-P(v)|\le 1$.

Let $N(u)=\{v\in V, (u, v) \in E\}$.
Then we construct $A \subset V$ with the following algorithm:

- Initialization: $m(u)=0$ for all $u\in V$.
- For all vertex $u$, let $B_u=\{v\in N(u),v \le u\}$. If $B_u$ is connected and $N(u)\subset N(B_u)$, then $m(u)=1$.
- Let $A = \{u\in V, m(u)=0\}$.

So far it's easy to see that $A$ is a [dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) of $G$. Now I'd like to analyze the average size of $A$ as $n \to \infty$. I guess that the goal is to construct a small dominating set (in average). Any advice?

Comment: In the definition of $B_u$, I'm guessing you meant $m(v) \le m(u)$?

Comment: Is the algorithm you describe supposed to be iterated until $m$ stabilizes?

Comment: @Micapps: No, it's really $\{v \in N(u), v \le u\}$ (I defined $V$ as $\{0, \ldots, n - 1\}$). And it's just a single pass ($m$ is just there in order to select the nodes at the end). In other words, I defined $A$ as the complement of the set of all nodes $u$ such that $B_u$ is connected and $N(u) \subset N(B_u)$. Nodes such that $m(u)=1$ are kind of "useless", so we construct a dominating set with the remaining nodes. I guess it would have been better this way.

Comment: Just another clarification: You're looking for an (asymptotic) dependence of the size of $A$ on $n$, with fixed $a,b$? For example, if $a=0, b= \frac{1}{2}$ then $A=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Micapps: That's it. BTW the values of $a$ and $b$ are not the point, let's say $a=0$ and $b=1$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it seems to me that $A$ does not contain any isolated points. How can it be a dominating set then?